# Height attribute when using picture and srcset

Tags: html, image, srcset

I am reading about `srcset` and see lots of examples like this one below. In order to tune pages to have a low CLS (Cumulative Layout Shift from LightHouse it's import that images have explicit height and width attributes ... but never see examples where the `srcset` has a height attribute. So how does the browser know how much space to reserve? Is the best practice to specify the `height` and `width` attributes in the `src` tag so that the browser can calculate the aspect ratio and therefore reserve display space? How does one ensure low CLS when using `srcset`?

```
    <img srcset="small.jpg 256w,
                 medium.jpg 512w,
                 large.jpg 1024w"
         src="medium.jpg"
         alt="It’s responsive!" />
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Good catch. The funny thing is, that's copypasta from a tutorial.